# Swing Timer stops calling actionPerformed() while the mouse is moving inside a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, timer, mouse, actionlistener

If I move my mouse inside a `javax.swing.JFrame`, the `javax.swing.Timer` stops calling the `actionPerformed()` method until the mouse stops moving. It only occurs when I move the cursor with my Rocket Kone XTD mouse. When I use my trackpad everything is fine.

How can I fix it? I'm using macOS Sierra.

Here's my code:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Mouse {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        Timer timer = new Timer(10, new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("foo");
            }
        });

        timer.start();
    }
}
```

To get an idea what I'm talking about:

[image]

### Code that gives more detail:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Mouse {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Note: Swing/AWT GUIs should be started on the EDT!
        // If the problem displayed here, that is first change I'd make to code.
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        Timer timer = new Timer(10, new ActionListener() {

            long lastTime = 0;

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                long nowTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                long difference = nowTime-lastTime;
                lastTime = nowTime;
                Rectangle r = frame.getBounds();
                Point p = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
                System.out.println(String.format("%1s\t%2s", 
                        difference, r.contains(p)));
            }
        });

        timer.start();
    }
}
```

### Output:

If the mouse is not moving, the output it looks like this:
11  true
13  true
13  true
10  true
12  true
13  true
12  true
13  true
10  true.

While the mouse is moving (fast) there is no output. When the mouse stops moving the output is: 2406    true (depending how long I moved my mouse).

If the mouse is moving slowly, the output looks like this: 17   true
5   true
8   true
16  true
4   true
11  true
16  true
44  true
11  true
28  true
48  true
77  true
11  true
7   true
15  true
8   true
9   true
12  true
24  true
13  true
4   true
12  true
32  true
13  true
8   true
8   true
13  true
10  true
15  true.

[image]

Comment: Did you test it on Windows or macOS? When I move my Kone XTD into the JFrame, the timer stops calling actionPerformed(). When I move my mouse outside of the JFrame or when I use my trackpad everything is fine.

Comment: Calling `frame.requestFocus();` has no effect for me :(

Comment: Calling Swing components from outside the `EDT` can have unpredictable behavior. This may or may not be the case here, but use `SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait` to place Swing calls on the EDT (eg all your code inside the `main` method should go inside)

Comment: Thanks for your response but this neither fix my problem.

Comment: Thank you. Using TimerTask is a working solution, but my problem also occurs when I add an animated gif (ImageIcon on a JLabel) to my JFrame. The animation stops while my mouse is moving. Is there a solution without animating the gif manually?

Comment: I've made an edit to add **Code that gives more detail**. Please provide the output of that code. Here, I'm not seeing a significant difference. Except for occasional outliers, I'm seeing 10, 11 or 12 for both true & false.

Comment: I added the output of your code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem as I reduced the polling-rate of my mouse from 1000Hz to 500Hz. Now everything works perfect. I think the problem was that the UI-Thread was overextended handling the 1000 polls per second so it was to busy to handle the `Timer`.