# GIF stops animating while gaming mouse is moving

Tags: java, macos, swing, timer, animated-gif

While I move my gaming mouse inside a `javax.swing.JFrame`, all animated GIFs (`javax.swing.ImageIcon` inside a `javax.swing.JLabel`) stops animating until the mouse stops moving.

This **only** happens with a gaming mouse with a driver on **macOS** (tested it with a Rocket-Kone XTD and a Razer gaming mouse on two computers). When I use other mice everything works fine.

The gaming mice also causing `javax.swing.Timer`s to stop calling their `actionPerformed()` methods. [I opened a thread here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40620829/swing-timer-stops-calling-actionperformed-while-the-mouse-is-moving-inside-a-j) for this problem, but this can be solved using `java.util.TimerTask` instead. (**Edit:** Actually TimerTask also don't fix it because the JFrame doesn't repaint until the mouse stops moving.)

But I found no alternative for animating GIFs. I'm more interested to solve the problem instead of using alternatives though I would be thankful for an working alternative too.

## Code:

```
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Mouse {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    new Mouse();
                }

            });
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public Mouse() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("waiting.gif")));

        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        frame.add(label);
    }
}
```

## Running application:

[image]

## MCVE:

```
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.net.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Mouse {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        new Mouse();
                    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            });
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public Mouse() throws MalformedURLException {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(
                new URL("https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXCUV.gif")));

        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        frame.add(label);
    }
}
```

Comment: I added a [mcve] as an edit. Do you see the same behaviour in the MCVE?

Comment: Yep it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Huh.. it works fine here. Put some code in the example to dump the Java version / micro-version of JRE.

Comment: Did u test it on a mac with a gaming mouse?

Comment: No, Windows with standard mouse. Have you tried it with other mice? On other OS?

Comment: Yes it only appears on mac using a gaming mouse. With a standart mouse everything works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem as I reduced the polling-rate of my mouse from 1000Hz to 500Hz. Now everything works perfect. I think the problem was that the UI-Thread was overextended handling the 1000 polls per second so it was to busy to animate the GIF.